# WebView2コントロールでInnerTextの更新が出来ない

Tags: javascript, c#

C#のWinFormでWebView2を使った開発をしています。
WebhookやGraph APIが使えないため、Microsoft Teamsに返信する処理をWebブラウザ経由で実現したいと考えています。

実行環境：Windows 10
開発環境：Visual Studio 2022
フレームワーク：.Net Framework 4.8

下記のようにinnerTextを書き換えようとしているのですが、JavaScriptを実行した後の戻り値は「bbb」になっているのに再度HTMLを取得しても変更前の値のままとなっています。（画面上もaaaのまま）
数日試行錯誤していますが解決できず、WebView2に関するノウハウがネット上にもほとんど無く行き詰っています。
お知恵を貸していただけないでしょうか。

```
<div id="new-message-12345678-9012-3456-7890-bcab739bbffa" placeholder="返信" tabindex="0" data-tid="ckeditor" data-is-focusable="true" class="ck ck-content ck-editor__editable ck-rounded-corners ck-editor__editable_inline ck-blurred" lang="en" dir="ltr" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" data-tabster="{&quot;focusable&quot;:{&quot;isDefault&quot;:true}, &quot;observed&quot;:{&quot;names&quot;:[&quot;chat-input&quot;]}}" style="overflow:hidden;" aria-label="返信">
    <p data-placeholder="返信">aaa</p>
</div>
```

■C#

```
string replyId = "new-message-12345678-9012-3456-7890-bcab739bbffa";
string html = await teamsWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('" + replyId + "').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;");
// 「aaa」が返る

string script = "document.getElementById('" + replyId + "').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = 'bbb';";
string result = await teamsWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
// resultには「bbb」が返る

html = await teamsWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('" + replyId + "').innerHTML;");
// 「aaa」が返る
```

Comment: こんなページが参考になるのでは？ [WebView2コントロールによるHTML要素の操作](https://web.biz-prog.net/operation/operation_wv.html), [WebBrowserからWebView2へ（４）](https://sysart-magazin.com/2021/03/03/webbrowser%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89webview2%E3%81%B8%EF%BC%88%EF%BC%94%EF%BC%89/), [WebBrowserからWebView2へ（５）](https://sysart-magazin.com/2021/03/04/webbrowser%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89webview2%E3%81%B8%EF%BC%88%EF%BC%95%EF%BC%89/) 後はCopilotで`WebView2 ExecuteScriptAsync html innerText 書き換え 更新されたことを確認する方法は有るか？`と聞くと [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) を使用する例が返されてきます。メソッド名的にも非同期なので、直ぐに実行されたとは限らないのでしょう。

Comment: @kunif さん　わざわざCopilotにまで聞いていただき、ありがとうございます。一般的なWebView2の使い方サイトは見ていて、ページの値取得は問題なく出来ているのですが、値の更新が上手く行かない状況です。リンクしていただいたページも解決につながりませんでした。

Comment: もしかして [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) ですかね？ 細かい何かの使い方ではなくて、もっと大前提的なテーマが何であるかから段階的に掘り下げた方が良いかもしれませんね。例えばTeamsで動作するチャットボット的な何かを作りたいとかでしょうか？ [Teams 用のボットを構築する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots)

Comment: @kunif さん　いえ、私は会社のOffice管理者でなく、Botも登録できません。そのため、WEBブラウザで手動できる操作を自動化したいと考えています

Comment: そういう操作の自動化ならWebView2を使うほどでは無く、MSならPowerAutomateとか、あるいはそれも管理者権限などの制約があるとしたら、他にはAutoHotKeyとかPyAutoGUIとかのRPAソフトで処理することが出来るのではありませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。現在は私はpower automate（デスクトップ版ではなくteamsアプリ）を使っています。ただ、リテラシー低い他の社員に手順書を渡しても設定が難しいようで、そうであればいっそ全て自動化したアプリケーションを開発して渡そうと思ったのがキッカケです。いろいろと別の角度からもアドバイスいただき、ありがとうございました。解決が難しそうなので諦めます。

Answer (score 1):

> 下記のようにinnerTextを書き換えようとしているのですが、JavaScriptを実行した後の戻り値は「bbb」になっているのに再度HTMLを取得しても変更前の値のままとなっています。（画面上もaaaのまま）

やり方の問題ではないのですか？　自分が試した限りでは期待通り書き換えられてますし、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

WebView2 上の表示も bbb に変わってます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**【追記】**

ちなみに、上の画像の WebView2 のアドレスバーの `https://localhost/WebForm38` というのは自分の開発環境に作った試験用の ASP.NET Web Forms アプリのページです。内容は以下通りで質問にある html ソースをコピペしたものです。ご参考まで。

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="WebForm38.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForms1.WebForm38" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            //const replyId = "new-message-12345678-9012-3456-7890-bcab739bbffa";

            //let result = document.getElementById(replyId).innerText;
            //console.log(result);

            //document.getElementById(replyId).getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = 'bbb';
            //let result1 = document.getElementById(replyId).getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
            //console.log(result1);

            //let result2 = document.getElementById(replyId).innerText;
            //console.log(result2);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="new-message-12345678-9012-3456-7890-bcab739bbffa" 
        placeholder="返信" 
        tabindex="0" 
        data-tid="ckeditor" 
        data-is-focusable="true" 
        class="ck ck-content ck-editor__editable ck-rounded-corners ck-editor__editable_inline ck-blurred" 
        lang="en" 
        dir="ltr" 
        role="textbox" 
        contenteditable="true" 
        data-tabster="{&quot;focusable&quot;:{&quot;isDefault&quot;:true}, &quot;observed&quot;:{&quot;names&quot;:[&quot;chat-input&quot;]}}" 
        style="overflow:hidden;" 
        aria-label="返信">
        <p data-placeholder="返信">aaa</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WebSurferさん　わざわざ実装してまで確認いただき、ありがとうございます。　[こういったサイト](https://jsfiddle.net/)でも構文エラーがないことは確認していたのですが、Teams側で外部からの書き換えを制御されているのかもしれません。ExecuteScriptAsyncで返信欄を選択後、sendkeysで入力値を送ることは出来ているのですが、対象のフォームが最前面にないといけない等、動作が保証されない点が気になって諦めきれず相談した感じです。構文の問題等ではなさそうなので、諦めます。ありがとうございました。